# Get relationships across multiple fields

Tags: laravel

How can I get relationship records across multiple fields

Following the example below, I want to return a category with id 2 only if all the conditions are met, namely option [1, 5, 8] with active = 1

Please help me, I searched through a lot of information and did not find a solution

````
`$options = [1, 5, 8];

$categories = Category::whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($options){
        $query->where(....);
    })->get();`
`
```
My Model Category


```
`class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, "category_id");
    }
}`
```

Table products

| id       | category_id | active | option |
| -------- | ----------- | ------ | ------ |
| 1        | 2           | 1      | 1      |
| 2        | 13          | 1      | 2      |
| 3        | 28          | 0      | 3      |
| 4        | 2           | 1      | 5      |
| 5        | 2           | 1      | 8      |
```
````

Comment: You can use `$query->whereIn('option', $options)`, i'm not sure if it"s what you are trying to do though, you can also add a `->where('active', 1)` on top of it

Comment: The solution did not help

Comment: Well it does solve the issue you are having, which is filtering records that match `active = 1` and `option IN [1, 5, 8]`, so if it does not solve your issue that means you didn't explain fully your problem. If you mean to actually retrieve that relationship records, that's another story, you should use `->with(['products' => function() { // same query here //}])`

Comment: to use your example, if you change option from 8 active = 0 in the products table, category 2 is still returned and should not

Comment: Category 2 has two active products with id 1 & 4, which also match option 1 & 5, so it will be returned, it only need one match to be returned

Comment: That's just my question in this, how to find by complete coincidence, return only if all products are active

Comment: Well it's not clear to me, where all conditions are met = where "option" condition and "active" condition are met

Comment: Please help me how to fix it

Comment: You should look for the withWhereHas function i think it does what you are trying to do, ex : `->withWhereHas('products', function() { // your query // } , '=', 3)`, it will return only when the specified number of results is found, and you can use `= 3`, or `> 2` depending on your needs

Comment: Return only if option 1,5,8 with active = 1

Comment: I think you can't do that with a whereHas, it will return it when there is one result at least

Answer (score 0):

```php
$options = [1, 5, 8];
$categories = Category::whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($options){
        $query->whereIn('option',$options)->where('active',1);
    })->get();
```